# Convert Json with array of arrays to columns in Sql server

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server, multidimensional-array

I have the json (example) below:

```
'{"X":["x1","x2","x3"],"Y":["y1","y2","y3"],"Z":[["x1y1","x1y2","x1y3"],["x2y1","x2y2","x2y3"],["x3y1","x3y2","x3y3"],["x4y1","x4y2","x4y3"],["x5y1","x5y2","x5y3"]]}'
```

(the true json has numbers, but for the example i am using strings)
It represents values in tree dimentions (X,Y,Z)

I would like to convert that json into columns, like the table below:

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | y1 | x1y1 |
| x1 | y2 | x1y2 |
| x1 | y3 | x1y3 |
| x2 | y1 | x2y1 |
| x2 | y2 | x2y2 |
| x2 | y3 | x2y1 |
| .. | .. | .... |
| .. | .. | .... |

How would be the SELECT statement ?

Comment: `Z` seems to be a nested array. Is this expected? The json contains a list of column values instead of rows too. Frankly, the *easiest* way would be to use a Python script with `sp_execute_external_script`, load this into a DataFrame, return it and write the output. JSON functions are *not* meant for reshaping data

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, Z is a nested array, because for each X,Y combination there is a Z value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to do a dynamic `JSON_VALUE` lookup based on the cross-join of `X` and `Y` properties.

Note that dynamic JSON paths only work in SQL Servre 2017 onwards, not 2016.

```sql
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = '{"X":["x1","x2","x3"],"Y":["y1","y2","y3"],"Z":[["x1y1","x1y2","x1y3"],["x2y1","x2y2","x2y3"],["x3y1","x3y2","x3y3"],["x4y1","x4y2","x4y3"],["x5y1","x5y2","x5y3"]]}';

SELECT
  x = x.value,
  y = y.value,
  z = JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.Z[' + x.[key] + '][' + y.[key] + ']')
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.X') x
CROSS JOIN OPENJSON(@json, '$.Y') y;
```

For SQL Server 2016, you instead just need to cross-join everything and filter afterwards

```sql
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = '{"X":["x1","x2","x3"],"Y":["y1","y2","y3"],"Z":[["x1y1","x1y2","x1y3"],["x2y1","x2y2","x2y3"],["x3y1","x3y2","x3y3"],["x4y1","x4y2","x4y3"],["x5y1","x5y2","x5y3"]]}';

SELECT
  x = x.value,
  y = y.value,
  z = z2.value
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.X') x
CROSS JOIN OPENJSON(@json, '$.Y') y
JOIN OPENJSON(@json, '$.Z') z1 ON z1.[key] = x.[key]
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(z1.value) z2
WHERE z2.[key] = y.[key];
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/YkVdWMvO)